# R alphabet support for åäöü

Tags: r, unicode

I need to enter non-english text data into R, but symbols åäöü gets substituted with wierd symbols like †.

Does R support reading character strings from alternative alphabets?

Comment: [Unicode](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Unicode/Unicode.pdf) package for R should help you.

Comment: If I type `x <- c("åäöü")` my R does not convert letters to weird symbols. Maybe it is a matter of encoding. What does `Sys.getlocale()` gives to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R has support for Unicode. [RStudio not picking the encoding I'm telling it to use when reading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324872/rstudio-not-picking-the-encoding-im-telling-it-to-use-when-reading-a-file)

Set your preferences in RStudio using the instructions from the link above.

Functions like `read.csv` and `readLines` have `encoding` options where you can specify something like "UTF-8".

`iconv` also exists to convert between encodings. There is also an extensive `stringi` library dedicated to string manipulation.