# read_excel returns Unicode characters instead of a table

Tags: r, unicode, unzip, import-from-excel

I would like to get a table from an Excel sheet using `readxl` package. I have the following code:

```
dir = tempfile()
download.file("http://www.kase.kz/files/market_valuation/ru/2017/val170502170509.zip", dir)
unzip(dir, list = TRUE)
file = unzip(dir, list = TRUE)[2, 1]
xl = read_excel(file, sheet = 1)
xl
```

And the result that I am getting is:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 11
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      `42857`
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        <chr>
1 <U+041E><U+0431><U+043B><U+0438><U+0433><U+0430><U+0446><U+0438><U+0438> <U+043C><U+0435><U+0436><U+0434><U+0443><U+043D><U+0430><U+0440><U+043E><U+0434><U+043D><U+044B><U+0445> <U+0444><U+0438><U+043D><U+0430><U+043D><U+0441><U+043E><U+0432><U+044B><U+0445> <U+043E><U+0440><U+0433><U+0430><U+043D><U+0438><U+0437><U+0430><U+0446><U+0438><U+0439>
2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  <U+2116> <U+043F>/<U+043F>
3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        <NA>
4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           1
5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           2
6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           3
7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           4
# ... with 10 more variables: X__1 <chr>, X__2 <chr>, X__3 <chr>, X__4 <chr>, X__5 <chr>, X__6 <chr>, X__7 <chr>, X__8 <chr>, X__9 <chr>, X__10 <chr>
```

Can anybody suggest a solution to this please?

After some corrections:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 11
                                         `42857`         X__1         X__2         X__3                          X__4              X__5
                                           <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>                         <chr>             <chr>
1 Облигации международных финансовых организаций         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>                          <NA>              <NA>
2                                          № п/п          НИН         ISIN Торговый код Краткое наименование эмитента Дней до погашения
3                                           <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>                          <NA>              <NA>
4                                              1 KZP01Y05E384 KZ2D00002623  EABRK281217     Евразийский банк развития               236
5                                              2 KZP02Y05E382 KZ2D00002631  EABRK250418     Евразийский банк развития               353
6                                              3 KZP03Y05E380 KZ2D00002763  EABRK180819     Евразийский банк развития               826
7                                              4 KZP04Y05E388 KZ2D00002771  EABRK180919     Евразийский банк развития               856
# ... with 5 more variables: X__6 <chr>, X__7 <chr>, X__8 <chr>, X__9 <chr>, X__10 <chr>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an Excel file instead of a CSV? As for Unicode, that's how any UTF8 encoded file would look if your R console or R Studio isn't set to display Unicode text

Comment: I am positive. Looked at it manually :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change your locale settings, you can do this using `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "russian")`, Once I have changed the settings to russian I am able to see the UTF-8 to russian alphabets, though I am however not sure about the region you are in .

To go back to prior settings I have used `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "english")` , under these settings I am getting U+XXX values for the russain (cyrillic) alphabets.

I am having below column names with russian locale:

```
> names(xl)
 [1] "№ п/п"                                      
 [2] "НИН"                                        
 [3] "ISIN"                                       
 [4] "Торговый код"                               
 [5] "Краткое наименование эмитента"              
 [6] "Дней до погашения"                          
 [7] "без дисконта, \"чистая\""                   
 [8] "без дисконта, \"грязная\""                  
 [9] "с  дисконтом, \"грязная\" (для целей биржи)"
[10] "Цена прошлого периода, % (без дисконта)"    
[11] "Ставка купона, %"
```

Table:

[image]

Please backup your locale settings before you work this solution.

You can do :

```
oldloc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")

Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "ru_RU")

Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", oldloc)
```

Try it may be it will help you. Thanks

Comment: were you able to see the table?

Comment: also, getting `In Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "ru_RU") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "ru_RU" cannot be honored`

Comment: @AK88, I am getting the table, I have attached it in the answer, for the other error, not sure why you are getting it try using `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "russian")` , however restart r  and then rerun this

Comment: Thank you for your time. Just restarted... still getting the above error ... will have to fix that first.

Comment: @AK88 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881731/strange-characters-interaction-of-r-and-windows-locale    and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345132/sys-setlocale-request-to-set-locale-cannot-be-honored

Comment: Fixed it! Adding the resulting table in the main body of OP. Do you know why the sub-columns are not showing?

Comment: I think it is because of merged cells in your excel sheet, there is a discussion about it. https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/99 and https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/166, for me i have unmerged the cells before reading it. My computer got frozed while importing the excel sheet while it was merged.

Comment: Hmmm ... `As discussed in #220 and above, it's best to handle these problems via other packages. There are no near term plans to get into merged cell issues here`. Gotta play with `tidyxl`.